# GWT issue with disabled fields (Chrome only)

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, gwt

I am quite new to GWT. I have an issue with an existing application. I have a View instance and a window with entity editor being displayed over it when needed (to create new object or edit one).
Now if I try to create 2 objects in a row, I get a weird result (only in Chrome). Probably because of some actions taken during saving/closing of the pop-up, when I open the pop-up editor for the second time, all fields are disabled.

I thought that GWT was meant to behave in the same way regardless of the browser.
What approach would you take to solve such a problem?

Comment: Hi. It's somewhat difficult to understand your issue. Some of your code would be helpful. And no, the popup shouldn't have disabled fields unless there exists some code to explicitly disable them. You can try setting a breakpoint in the `setEnabled()` method of some field, and see if any part of code hits it at runtime causing it to disable.

Comment: I know that this is a very general question and the code snippet would be nice to have but I think that the problem is not related to the code itself since in browsers other than Chrome all works fine. It could be some idiosyncracies caused by the browser or the GWT compiled version. When I try to watch the web traffic in Fiddler or browser web tools, the .rpc calls are all encrypted. I know that GWT compiler creates a 'permutation' for each browser during compilation but how would you compare them? What would you do on my place?